# Why is my register and login system looping in python?

Tags: python

This is my login and register system for a game I am programming. However when I try to login using the username and password stored on the text file, it keeps printing "Incorrect credentials" and looping me back to "Please enter your username player 1" and repeating this process. Any feedback on improving and fixing the code would be greatly appreciated. (I am using python 3.6.0)

```
abc = input("Enter 'n' if a player needs to make a new account, otherwise enter anything to login")

new_users = False    
if abc == "n":
    while new_users == False:
        username = input("Please input a username ")
        password = input("Please input a password ")
        file = open("users.txt","a")
        file.write(username)
        file.write(" ")
        file.write(password)
        file.write("\n")
        file.close()
        repeat = input("Enter 'n' to make another account, or type anything else to continue")
        if repeat == "n":
            new_users = False
        else:
            new_users = True
                    

logged_in1 = False
logged_in2 = False
while logged_in1 == False:
    username = input("Please enter your username player 1")
    password = input("Please enter your password player 1")
    for line in open("users.txt","r").readlines():
        login_info = line.split()
        if username == login_info[0] and password == login_info[1]:
            print("Correct credentials!")
            logged_in1 = True
        else:
            print("Incorrect credentials.")
            break
            logged_in1 = False

while logged_in2 == False:
    username = input("Please enter your username player 2")
    password = input("Please enter your password player 2")
    for line in open("users.txt","r").readlines():
        login_info = line.split()
        if username == login_info[0] and password == login_info[1]:
            print("Correct credentials!")
            logged_in2 = True
        else:
            print("Incorrect credentials.")
            break
            logged_in2 = False
```

[this is what the text file currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Mq3K.png)

Comment: Can you show the txt file? I think you are making/parsing it incorrectly

Comment: I've attached an image of the text file at the bottom of my post. Currently there are two user names and passwords on there.

Answer (score 0):

Your `break` statement is in the wrong place. You need to break out of the `for` loop as soon as you have found that the credentials are correct. Here's a proposed change:

```
logged_in1 = False
logged_in2 = False
while logged_in1 == False:
    username = input("Please enter your username player 1")
    password = input("Please enter your password player 1")
    for line in open("users.txt","r").readlines():
        login_info = line.split()
        if username == login_info[0] and password == login_info[1]:
            print("Correct credentials!")
            logged_in1 = True
            break
    if not logged_in1:
        print("Incorrect credentials.")

while logged_in2 == False:
    username = input("Please enter your username player 2")
    password = input("Please enter your password player 2")
    for line in open("users.txt","r").readlines():
        login_info = line.split()
        if username == login_info[0] and password == login_info[1]:
            print("Correct credentials!")
            logged_in2 = True
            break
    if not logged_in2:
        print("Incorrect credentials.")
```

Also, determining that the credentials are incorrect can only happen after the loop is over.